# downloading file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want a user to download a file which is in tabular format with header along with two search widgets on top. The output is forecasted values along with 80%(High-low) and 95%(High-low) confidence interval.So there are five columns, five rows(default). However, i am having two challenges here.

Challenge 1:
When I run the app, after clicking on "Download the file" filename is coming as download data with no extension whereas I have mentioned filename should be "forecasted" with png extension and it should come as forecated.png

Challenge 2: After typing png as extension while saving the file, the file is saved but nothing gets printed.

I have searched in various forums and try to replicate them but nothing seems to be working.

Please suggest.

shiny UI

```
library(shiny)    
downloadButton(outputId = "downloaddata" ,label ="Download the file"),
```

shiny server

```
output$downloaddata<-downloadHandler(

    filename = function(){
      paste("forecasted","png",sep=",")
    },
    content = function(file){
      png(file)
      h <-input$fst
      tab<-forecast(Model_mape(),h) 
      datatable(as.data.frame(tab), options = list(
         columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1, 3), searchable = FALSE)),
         pageLength = 10))
      dev.off()

    }

  )
```

Comment: some time you need to open the app in browser to download the plots and datasets

Comment: I can't try it for myself, but does the code between `png()` and `dev.off()` actually plot something. I can't see any obvious functions that would do so.

Comment: Can you put the entire code ? That we could run it and find your problem (we need the plot or data that you want to download for instance)

Comment: You probably want a period instead of a comma in the `filename` function. In fact, if that's your actual code, just use `filename = function() "forecasted.png"`.

Comment: @Jarko Dubbeldam yes it plots in the plot tab in Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help you (it's a simple instance):

Ui :

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"),
           downloadButton("downloadplot","Download your plot"))

  ))
```

Server :

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  your_plot = function(){
    (plot(rnorm(1000,0,1)))
  }


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    your_plot()
  })

  output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "plot_exemple.png",
    content = function(file) {
      png(file, width = 1200, height = 800)
      print(your_plot())
      dev.off()
    })

  })
```

With this, you can easily download a png (open it in a browser).